# Where should bundle class and routing.yaml be with the Symfony 5 bundle structure?

Tags: symfony

With the [Symfony 4.4 bundle file structure](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/bundles.html#bundle-directory-structure) you had

```
foo-bundle
├─ Resources
│  └─ config
│     └─ routing.yaml
└─ FooBundle.php
```

In the `routes.yml` of the application you would load the bundle's routes like this:

```
foo_bundle:
  resource: '@FooBundle/Resources/config/routing.yaml'
```

With the [Symfony 5 bundle structure](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html#bundle-directory-structure) you have:

```
foo-bundle
├─ config
│  └─ routing.yaml
└─ src
   └─ FooBundle.php
```

But it seems paths are relative to `FooBundle.php` and in the application's `routes.yml` you can't use `..`, i.e. this is not valid:

```
  resource: '@FooBundle/../config/routing.yaml'
```

Then how can I load the bundle's routes?

The only way seems to move ``FooBundle.php` up one level, but then it would need special treatment in the autoloader and the [autoload example in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html#bundle-directory-structure) (green box) doesn't contain such special treatment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs are actually a little bit confusing on this one.  For 5.4 you need to tweak Bundle::getPath in order to use the new directory structure.  For 6.x the new AbstractBundle class does this for you.

```
class MyBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getPath(): string
    {
        if (null === $this->path) {
            $reflected = new \ReflectionObject($this);
            // assume the modern directory structure by default
            $this->path = \dirname($reflected->getFileName(), 2); // The 2 is key
        }

        return $this->path;
```

It is perhaps worth pointing out that the 5.4 docs still show the old bundle structure.  It's generally worth setting the correct doc version when reading the docs just to avoid these sorts of problems.  But again the latest docs do say the change was in Symfony 5.

Comment: Oh, I was looking at the Symfony 6 docs while using Symfony 5.4. That explains a lot.